# Como importar um ficheiro csv para um JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Alguém sabe passar de um ficheiro csv para uma jtable? Actualmente mas lista tudo na primeira coluna.

```
private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();

        try {
           File file = new File("Users.csv");
           if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }

           FileReader fr = new FileReader(file.getAbsoluteFile());
           BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

           String line;


           while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                model.addRow(new String[] {line});



            }
           br.close();
           fr.close();

        }catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Adicione um **[mcve]** do seu código e um trecho com exemplo dos dados do seu csv para que seja possivel simular o problema.

Comment: Normalmente arquivos csv vem semparados por ponto e virgula (;) ou outro caractere delimitador. Faça a quebra da String pelo delimitador dentro do while e depois monte o array de string com os valores quebrados pra que cada um fique em uma celula da tabela.

Comment: pode mostrar um exemplo @WagnerSoares ?

Answer (score 0):

Altere seu `while` assim, supondo que seu `.csv` seja com 3 colunas e separados por ponto e virgula (dados1;dados2;dados3)

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
      //estou dividindo em um array quebrando a linha pelos ponto e virgula
      String colunas[] = line.split(";");

      //passo para o model cada item da linha separadamente
      model.addRow(new String[] {colunas[0], colunas[1], colunas[2]});

}
```

Não tive como testar aqui no trabalho, mas deve funcionar.